# Prove by induction sums of powers of 4

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, induction

Hello how can I prove this with using induction, not telescopic sums?

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^4 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30}$$

I^ve tried to sum up the right hand side with $$(n+1)^4$$ in order to have
 $$  \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)(3(n^2+2n+1)+3n+2)}{30}$$
 however after all that algebra, i couldnt come up with a solution
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Denoting the RHS by $f(n)$ you must prove that $f(1)=1$ and $f(n)+(n+1)^4=f(n+1)$. Give it at least a try yourself.

Comment: My question is how can I prove that using induction. Sorry for no including my work but i^ve tried to solve it about an hour and now I editted it. I tried thanks for your advicd :)

Comment: What you should have added to the RHS was $(n+1)^4$, not $r^4$.

Comment: I am sorry I meant I^ve tried what you said but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{r=1}^nr^4=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{(r+1)^5-r^5-10r^3-10r^2-5r-1}{5}=$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)^5-1-\frac{10n^2(n+1)^2}{4}-\frac{10n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{5n(n+1)}{2}-n}{5}=$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30}.$$

Done!

Comment: thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: The idea is so nice ! Moreover, usable for any power. $\to +1$.